# error: reference to non-static member function must be called

Tags: c++

On compiling, I am receiving this

```
error: reference to non-static member function must be called
                        std::sort(sortedCOPG_.begin(),sortedCOPG_.end(),comp_copgNode);
```

Can someone let me as what I am doing wrong? I tried almost the same code without the classes, but there the code didnt had issues. Its only after I encapsulated the code in a class. I have removed a lot code before posting here, to keep things simple. I tried other similar posts, but couldn't make sense out of it.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>

class Computation {
    public:

         Computation() {

        }

    private:

        struct copgNode_ {
            double weight;
            int source;
            int target;
        };


        template <typename Iter>
        void mst_score__( Iter first, Iter last) {
            Iter current = first;
            for (; current != last; ++current) {
                for (int i=0; i < n_; ++i) {
                    if (adjMatrix_[*current][i] != 0 ) sortedCOPG_.push_back(copgNode_{adjMatrix_[*current][i],*current,i});
                }
            }
            //Here, is the line causing errors---
            std::sort(sortedCOPG_.begin(),sortedCOPG_.end(),comp_copgNode);
        }

        void m_init_computation__() {

            std::vector<int> mst_test_vec{0,3,7};
            mst_score__(mst_test_vec.begin(),mst_test_vec.end());

    }


        bool comp_copgNode ( const copgNode_& left, const copgNode_& right) {return left.weight < right.weight;}    
};
```

Comment: `comp_copgNode` is a non-statc member function, you cannot refer to it like that . (How would `sort` know which object to call it on?)  Your simplest solution would be to make the function `static`, if it does not depend on a particular instance.

Comment: Where is `sortedCOPG` coming from?

Comment: @M.M : So, I should be using this operator to reference it?

Comment: @tadman: Thats a std::vector<copgNode> data structure, I have trimmed other functions that generate sortedCOPG. And its a class variable

Comment: No, you need to understand that non-static member functions can only be called on an instance of an object (or to put it another way, they have an implied `this` parameter, which `sort` doesn't know about)

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the bug, had to replace the compare function.
    As,  it would let the sort function to identify that custom comparator overrides the default comparator

```
friend bool operator< ( const copgNode_& left, const copgNode_& right) {return left.weight < right.weight;}
```

Comment: all you did was call the function `operator<` instead of `comp_copgNode`, that makes no difference. Putting `friend` was the "solution" (which would have worked for `comp_copgNode` too)